# Mi, So, Re, Do?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, steganography, music

Not quite! But it's even easier to *do*! Here's what you'll need:

[image: 1st part]

[image: 2nd part]

[image: 3rd part]

[image: 4th part]

[image: 5th part]

[image: 6th part]

---

It *may?* help some people, but the title should have been:

> Mi So Re Do? (but the 15 char limit stopped that)

Also:

> The image was only broken up because the screen wasn't big enough to take screenshots.

Hints:

> 5 go like this: words -> music -> hidden word
>  2 go like this: words -> slightly hidden message
>  1 goes like this and should be the lead-in: words -> message (not really hidden)

> All the text is important

> 2 of the clues are about HOW to get the final answer
>  6 of the clues are WHAT you need to get the final answer

> Yes, a thick creamy dressing is relevant
>  What next? There are two linked clues in the music, the rest can be interpreted by itself then put into the music after
>  You might want to analyse the 'comments' for alternative meanings.

> 'More...*between the accents' could be 'More...* between the accents' for clarity

> On TSL @humn picked up on *So "far" - BAD* having **B-A-D**. This clue has 3 parts, of which BAD is one of them. (There is also a subtler hint)

> In that clue (^), two parts are how to decipher the music and one part tells you what in the music you need to decipher.

> @Volatility was correct in finding 'mayo': you need to find similar items

> Breakdown of *So "far" - BAD*: **So "far"** and **BAD** are what you need to decipher and **-** is what you need to look for

> The subtler hint is in the wording 'so far'

> **-** is a *tenuto* [which is basically a hyphen on a note, like the first note in the left hand (bottom line) in the 6th bar.

> Warning! One step of the solution!
>
> > Take the tenutos in the music. They give ADCABBAGE, but 'so far' we need to use solfa (i.e. before the message) so the first A gets turned into a re. This gives a message - REDCABBAGE or red cabbage.

> Sections are important - but what information *goes with* the letters that you are given?

> So... yes, the bar numbers are linked to the sections. Why don't you try applying some [**knowledge**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge) here (or ask google)?

> What can you do with {(O,11);(C,12);(H,22)}?

> The last part needs a bit of musical knowledge.

> @humn was semi-right when they said [they had found the last ingredient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktEl1.png) - something used there is correct.

> What elements of the music have you not yet used?

> Alright, I'll say it - it is morse code...

---

Unnecessary, but [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3gngymu144wacc/My_16th_Artwork.mid?dl=0) is the sound file (on Dropbox).

And [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kr10oy8lmvlgi2j/My_16th_Artwork.pdf?dl=0) is a PDF, but across two pages, and *'Made with MixIn'* is at the bottom of both pages (also Dropbox).

---

Perhaps a smidgen of [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) will be needed, but not too much.

Everything is clued in some way, so no need to do something radical.

---

**For reference, I use a [movable do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Movable_do_solf.C3.A8ge)**

Comment: "So" or "Sol"??

Comment: @lois6b At least one other source does it 'so': https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGLJL.png. Anyway, that's what I learnt at school - maybe it's the Australian version.

Comment: okey sorry for my comment. what is the expected answer?  a thing? a word?

Comment: @lois6b You'll know it when you've got it - it'll be pretty obvious.

Comment: Come for the puzzle but stay for the MIDI, it rocks! (The cha-cha-cha-cha power chords give it a modern feel,) Who knows, hearing this might help solution. After following along with the score, the details are much more vivid and easy to remember.

Comment: @humn Oh no! I want this to stay unsolved - I bid you forget it! :D

Comment: "So no need to do something radical"? Like charting chords? I'd be glad to stop after getting 1/3 through without a keyboard for double checking.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the composer "Mei O." sounds like Mandarin for "do(es) not have". It also sounds like [a thick, creamy dressing often used as a condiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayonnaise).

Comment: Since this is missing the computer tag, I would assume it's not related to [velato](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Velato)

Comment: @tfitzger No, not related to that.

Comment: @Volatility - That rea**l**ly m**a**y be *w*or**t**h men**t**ion*in*g ... ac*k*nowl**e**dged (**r**eiterated)

Comment: "For Chopin"... If this is a shopping list, it seems very impractical to use :P

Comment: @WesleySitu That's what a non-puzzler would say :P. But you've correctly picked up on one clue… (well, there's another interpretation of that clue that might get you further)

Comment: An observation on the accents: They're placed where notes can be (could just be how MixIn places them). Though I've tried converting them to letters / solfege (and also what "between" could mean) but.... no results. And wait... is MixIn even a real application? Could just be another instruction.

Comment: @WesleySitu Could just be another instruction indeed ... ;) In other matters - no, the accents don't need to be converted into notes. They just mark notes of importance (accents are literally marked notes in music). I'll now release a hint.

Comment: I've never heard of a composer named "Mei O" (which could possibly be 没哦）:P

Comment: C12H22O11 is the chemical formula of sugar

Comment: @elias Correct.

Answer (score 12):

### Partial answer

> It is a recipe for coleslaw (thanks [Forklift](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36638/forklift)). The ingredients are red cabbage, and carrot for chopping, and after mayonnaise and sugar are added, made with mixing.

#### How

For Chopin (thanks [Jason](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/271/jason))

> **For chopping**

Made with MixIn

> **Made with mixing** (MixIn is *not* a piece of software at all)

#### What

Composed by Mei O. (thanks [Volatility](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/8949/volatility))

> Composed by **Mayo**

BETWEEN this bar ... [OR] this bar?

> "BETWEEN this bar" is at bar 1, "[OR] this bar?" is at bar 26, and `||` is (logical) OR in programming. This means to translate section lengths to letters in the alphabet. (thanks OP) There are double barlines at bars 16, 30, 39 and 54, splitting the song into sections with length 15, 14, 9, 15 and 14 - **onion**

From hint given by OP

> Take the tenutos in the music. They give ADCABBAGE, but 'so far' we need to use solfa (i.e. before the message) so the first A gets turned into a re. This gives a message - REDCABBAGE or **red cabbage**.

My 16th artwork

> The semiquavers are arranged in a pattern (thanks [humn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18129/humn)).
>  It appears to be in the shape of a **carrot**. Image is at the bottom of the post.

Sectional form

> The sections O, C and H are bars 11, 12 and 22 respectively. C<sub>12</sub>H<sub>22</sub>O<sub>11</sub> is the chemical formula for sucrose, or table **sugar**.

#### Done: 7/8

**Not done**

- More... * the accents - C, C, G, D, E, and B, D, GBDG chord near the end - what does the asterisk symbolize?

  > This appears to be horseradish, both according to number of notes and the section hint (H is not yet known)

Image of full score is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk0vo.png) if anyone needs one

> [image: Semiquaver pattern]

Comment: The sections thing is correct so far, is there any information linked to the sections? The rest you'll still need quite a bit more info for.

Comment: Great suspicion about 16ths . . . they seem to form a $\nabla$-ish diagram over the entire score!

Comment: Or perhaps "for chopping"?

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure, one of the ingredients are one that isn't exactly possible to chop

Comment: @humn Your suspicions are well founded. Why not make an answer?

Comment: @Jason "For chopping" is correct

Comment: Can't believe I hadn't looked at this in an overall way, @boboquack, and am cheering this solution now

Comment: @humn So what's the pattern?

Comment: No, it's not a blade. For Chopin is a totally separate clue

Comment: The shape could be a wedge.

Comment: Does the direction of the accent have meaning (to the puzzle, not to music)?

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush Well accents only *have* one direction in music

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush Official confirmation - no

Comment: Between this bar ... [OR] this bar is the double-barline thingy - in computer programming, || means OR, and the bars they are in are 1 and 26

Comment: @boboquack Well technically in programming `|` means OR as well (bitwise OR)

Comment: BTW see the new hint, maybe it can help you. But why are you *thanking* me?

Comment: @boboquack The new hint isn't helping haha, all I can think of are the section positions, which *do* seem relevant, but I can't seem to figure out in what way

Comment: Part of an ingredient detected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktEl1.png

Comment: @humn The H isn't there though

Comment: Right, somebody, although "eat" is.  There are barely enough dots left over for an H even if rearranged. And I wouldn't be surprised if the 1-or-2-line-tall slices of the entire score need to be rearranged for some purpose.

Comment: OP confirmed [morse](http://www.dcode.fr/morse-code). I've transcribed the relevant info. `- >.. -.. -- >.. > .. > . > .. .>. -- . - - > -. .. >` Spaces between measures.

Comment: @feelinferrety what could that mean :/ that there's more Morse?

Comment: -shrug- just figured folks might like to take another crack at it, possibly re-space or add characters in (still don't know what the **\*** note means)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to somebody's answer:

> Chopping red cabbage and mixing with mayo sounds like a recipe for coleslaw.

Comment: I had the same thought...

Comment: This is the final answer, but you need ingredients to make it!

Comment: Ha! Maybe the way you make it :) I'm ready to eat!

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

The title say:

> "Mi, So, Re, Do?"

and in the [english system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature_names_and_translations) is:

> "E, G, D, C?"

Seems that the body `"Not quite! But it's even easier to do!"` is answering whatever the title is saying.

I tried reading at loud the letters to *form* words but except from `"C"` being `"See"` I dont get the question in the title

Comment: If you look at the edit history it says: ***2** Put a bad pun in*. This really was just a pun, and is not necessary for the puzzle. Sorry! :(

Comment: thanks for the info, forgot to look the edit comment hehe

Comment: @boboquack im so stuck xDDD cant figure it out

Comment: @lois6b Perhaps the title is some kinda word trick: Am I sorry Dio? :P

Comment: @MikeLimburg nice *translation* hahah who is Dio?XD the body answering do not make sense with that question

Comment: @lois6b Haha, I was thinking far outside the box, to gather some ideas... By the way, Ronnie Dio is (well, was) a famous American singer. But I guess that's not what OP means. ;)

Comment: If you transpose to C, you would have Mi So Re Do in the first bar, but what is there is Ti Re La So, i.e. "not quite!" Not sure how that helps.

Comment: @shoover I use a movable do.

Comment: @boboquack That's funny, because my original comment assumed a movable do! But then I second-guessed myself and looked it up and found that more commonly Do is equated to C no matter what key you're in. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "do" is italicized in the question. Switching it to "C" we get "Not quite! But it's even easier to _see_!" Another possibly useless bit: the note _numbers_ in the key of G are 6, 1, 5, 4.

Comment: I just keep thinking of Misery from the fact that it was clarified that the title  was intended to have no commas. Not sure where the 'do' comes in though.